# How to change elements of tuples nested within a list

Tags: python

Straight off the bat I'm new to programming so apologies in advance for asking a basic question. I have researched previous answers but I'm still stuck. Im working on the following problem:

Q:
Write a Character Creator program for a role-playing game. The player should be given a pool of points to spend on four attributes: Strength, Health, Wisdom, Dexterity. The player should be able to spend points on any attribute and should also be able to take points from an attribute and put them back into the pool.

I've found this solution, but I'm not satisfied, as it uses terms not yet taught in the book, and doesnt contain lists or dictionaries (the entire chapter was on this so I'd expect the end-of-chapter exercises to require the new knowledge).
https://github.com/malmhaug/Py_AbsBegin/tree/master/Ch5E2_CreateCharacter

Please may I have some help: here is what ive got so far.

Thanks in advance

```
#Character creator program; players have 30 points to spend across 4 attributes
#Players can also change their choices

#character attributes
character = [('Strength', 0), ('Health', 0), ('Wisdom', 0), ('Dexterity', 0)]

total = 30
int(total)
print('\nYou have ', total, 'points to spend')

choice = None
while choice != '0':
    print(
'''
Please choose an option: \n
\t0: Exit
\t1: Display CV
\t2: Denote Strength
\t3: Denote Health
\t4: Denote Wisdom
\t5: Denote Dexterity
\t6: Change an attribute

'''
)

    choice = input('Choice ')
    print()

#Exit
    if choice == '0':
        print('Goodbye')
        break
    elif choice == '1':
        print('Your Character:')
        print('Attibute\tLevel')
        for i in character:
            print(i)

    elif choice == '2': #Adds points to the Strength value whilst
                        #subtracting them from total

        character[0] = (attribute, value)
        strength = int(input('How strong is your character? '))
        if strength <= total:
            value = strength
            total -= strength
            print('You have ', total,'points remaining')
        elif strength > total:
            print('You dont have enough points')
        else:
            print('Sorry, invalid entry')

    elif choice == '3': #Adds points to the Health value whilst
                        #subtracting them from total

        attribute, value = ('Health', 0)
        health = int(input('How robust is your character? '))
        if health <= total:
            value = health
            total -= health
            print('You have ', total,'points remaining')
        elif health > total:
            print('You dont have enough points')
        else:
            print('Sorry, invalid entry')

    elif choice == '4': #Adds points to the Wisdom value whilst
                        #subtracting them from total

        attribute, value = ('Wisdom', 0)
        wisdom = int(input('How wise is your character? '))
        if wisdom <= total:
            value = wisdom
            total -= wisdom
            print('You have ', total,'points remaining')
        elif wisdom > total:
            print('You dont have enough points')
        else:
            print('Sorry, invalid entry')

    elif choice == '5': #Adds points to the Dexterity value whilst
                        #subtracting them from total

        attribute, value = ('Dexterity', 0)
        dexterity = int(input('How dextrous is your character? '))
        if dexterity <= total:
            value = dexterity
            total -= dexterity
            print('You have ', total,'points remaining')
        elif dexterity > total:
            print('You dont have enough points')
        else:
            print('Sorry, invalid entry')


    elif choice == '6': #Changes the 'value' element in the tuple, chosen by the
                        #user's input



        for skill in character: #shows the user the current character attributes
            print(skill)

        change = input('Enter an attribute to change: ')#the attriute to change
        for skill in character:#iterates over the list's tuples

            if change == skill[0]:#tests the change string against the element in the 1st position of each tuple
                total += skill[1]
                value = int(input('What do you want the new value to be? '))#sets the new value to the second element of the tuple

                if value <= total:
                        total -= new_value
                        print('You have ', total,'points remaining')
                elif new_value > total:
                    print('You dont have enough points')
                else:
                    print('Sorry, invalid entry')
input('\n\nPress enter to exit')
```

Comment: can you please cut straight to the chase both with the question description as well as with the code provided?

Comment: why use a list of tuples instead of a dict?

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, therefore you cannot change a value inside them.

I suggest you use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the elements in `character` , you should either use a dictionary , or a nested list , or a tuple of lists , but you can't use a list of tuples
dict :

```
character = { 'Strength' : 0, 'Health' : 0, 'Wisdom' : 0, 'Dexterity' : 0 }
```

list :

```
character = [ ['Strength', 0], ['Health', 0], ['Wisdom', 0], ['Dexterity', 0] ]
```

tuple :

```
character = ( ['Strength', 0], ['Health', 0], ['Wisdom', 0], ['Dexterity', 0] )
```

Now if you want to add 10 points to 'Strength' , you can do `character['Strength'] += 10` , in case of dict , or `character[0][1] += 10` , if you want to use a list or tuple